# PHP readfile() returning corrupted data

Tags: php, cakephp, header, readfile

In my function I am saving an image decoded from a base64 string:

```
function saveImage(){
    //magic...
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', '../webroot/img/');
    $base64string = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64string);
    $base64string = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64string);
    $data = base64_decode($base64string);
    $id = uniqid();
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR.$id.'.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
}
```

The above function works properly and the images are saved and not corrupted in the specified folder.

In the next function I am now trying to force download the image to a user:

```
function getChart($uniqid= null){
    if($uniqid){
        $this->layout = null;
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='".$uniqid.".png'");
        readfile('../webroot/img/'.$uniqid.'.png');
        exit;
    } else exit;
}
```

Image downloaded from the server is corrupted and cant be displayed. After opening the downloaded file in a text editor I noticed that a new line character is added at the very top. After deleting the character and saving the file it opens properly and is being displayed properly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure you are not outputing something before you call `readline`? the code looks fine to me

Comment: @Peter: You are outputting something. Point in case is more likely that you have a problem to understand where. As you write there is more output than just the headers and the readfile content.

Comment: yeah I just checked the buffer and something was being outputted. I dont know why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe can have multiple issues that are hidden until you actually open the downloaded file.

Instead make your code more robust and check pre-conditions, here if headers have been send already and to clean any possible existing output buffer and give error if that is not possible:

```
function getChart ($uniqid = null) {

    if (!$uniqid) exit;

    $this->layout = null;

    if (headers_sent()) throw new Exception('Headers sent.');
    while (ob_get_level() && ob_end_clean());
    if (ob_get_level()) throw new Exception('Buffering is still active.');

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='".$uniqid.".png'");
    readfile('../webroot/img/'.$uniqid.'.png');

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Content-length: $file_size")
```

This header tells the browser how large the file is. Some browser need it to be able to download the file properly. Anyway it's a good manner telling how big the file is. That way anyone who download the file can predict how long the download will take.

```
header("Content-type: $file_type")
```

This header tells the browser what kind of file it tries to download.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
```

This tells the browser to save this downloaded file under the specified name. If you don't send this header the browser will try to save the file using the script's name.

BUT you need to flush buffer, with `flush();` or in your case with `ob_flush();` right above first exit;

Comment: The significant advantage of using output buffering is when it's used alongside data compression. If you're not using ob_gzhandler, there's little to gain. flush alone will just commit whatever output data is still on the server. With ob_start and its counterparts ob_flush, ob_end_clean and ob_end_flush, whatever is waiting to be compressed (look at flush and ob_flush as referring to different buckets - flush sends data to ob, ob sends data to browser - may not be accurate but that's the idea) will be wrapped up and sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (to force download):

```
function getChart($uniqid= null){
    if($uniqid){

        $image = $uniqid;

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $image);
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($image);

    } else exit;
}

getChart("060620121945.jpg");
```

Try this (just to render image):

```
function getChart($uniqid= null){
    if($uniqid){

        $mime_type = "image/png";
        $content = file_get_contents('../webroot/img/'.$uniqid.'.png');
        $base64   = base64_encode($content); 
        return ('data:' . $mime_type . ';base64,' . $base64);

    } else exit;
}
```

Comment: how can I force download the image in your example?

Comment: @DusanRadojevic: Yes, but that is not the issue. Actually compare with the original code, you ended up the same. It is likely to have the exact same issues in OP's environment.

Answer (score 0):

check if you are outputing something before calling `readfile`:

```
// add ob_start() at the very top of your script
function getChart($uniqid= null){
    echo strlen(ob_get_clean()); die(); // if it's not 0 then you are definetly echoing something

    if($uniqid){
        $this->layout = null;
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='".$uniqid.".png'");
        readfile('../webroot/img/'.$uniqid.'.png');
        exit;
    } else exit;
}
```

Comment: You have output in buffer, it is likely a windows system CRLF sequence, but that is just a guess. See my answer, it cleans that for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12639730/367456

Comment: @Peter Check the places where you open / close the php tags. maybe there's a newline before the tags

Comment: unfortunately there there's not

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem several times. Here's the solution that I used:

Almost always it turned out that I had forgotten to turn off `unicode BOM` encoding in my `download.php` file which adds something to the front of the downloaded file and therefore corrupts it.

So the solution is to **turn off `unicode BOM` in `download.php`.**

Answer (score 0):

Just use ob_clean(); before readfile()